# Flatten a jsonb column dict into a list of dicts

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have jsonb column that has the data in the following structure

```
{
    'pid1':{
        'c_id1': 'val1',
        'c_id2': 'val2'
    },
    'pid2':{
        'c_id1': 'val3',
        'c_id2': 'val4'
    }
}
```

I need to update the values to just be a list of values like below

```
[ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
```

How can I do this using postgres jsonb functions or which function should I use to achieve this?

Edit: I am using postgres version 9.6 so `jsonb_path_query_array` is not supported

Comment: Is it always exactly two levels?

Comment: yes, exactly two levels

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path query for this:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$.*.*')
from the_table
```

Comment: Works great in postgres version >= 12. Any idea what to do for versions where this function is not supported.

Comment: @lambda in that case use `jsonb_each`